# .NET Core - ExecuteSqlRaw - IDENTITY_INSERT ON not working

Tags: sql, asp.net-core

I try to do a raw sql query, becos I need to insert a particular id when injecting data in the SQL db

I set the IDENTITY INSERT flag in C# : SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyDb-Dev].[dbo].[companies] ON

and when I run the query, it complains the flag is not set properly

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'companies' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

I tried :

- removing [MyDb-Dev]. from the first query but still the same
- running setIdentityInsert("companies", "ON"); TWICE and it never triggers any exception

here is my code (it never throws any exception so I guess it works)

```
private void setIdentityInsert(string table,string value)
{
    try
    {
        var sql = @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyDb-Dev].[dbo].[" + table + "] " + value;
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql);
        _logger.LogInformation(sql);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning(e.Message);
    }
}
```

- How can I figure if the SET IDENTITY_INSERT query worked correctly ?
- Why would that query run without affecting the SQL flag ?

thanks for your precious help

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this fails is because of a different session. Each request is its own session and `SET IDENTITY_INSERT = ON` is valid only for the current version. You will have to rework using string construction to append your query along side the `IDENTITY_INSERT = ON`

Comment: oh that makes sens, I should prepend the query so it's in the same session...thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, entity is really not the best partner in this story

one got to do

```
_context.Database.OpenConnection();
```

before the first query